# Radioactive decay differential equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, differential-equations, radioactivity, calculus

I am trying to form a differential equation between two different isotopes, Uranium-238 and Thorium-234. 
The rate of decay of an isotope is proportional to the amount present. So that: 
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = -kx
$$
Where x is the amount of Uranium-238 and k is the constant if proportionality. Also,
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = -cx
$$
Where y is the amount of Thorium-234 and c is the constant if proportionality.

I have also been told that:
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} + cx = kxe^{-kt}
$$

I am trying to find the general solution to the differential equation above. I have found the integrating factor which is:

$$
Ae^{ct}
$$
And I have multiplied all the terms by the integrating factor to get:

$$
Ae^{ct}\frac{dy}{dt} + Ae^{ct}cx = kxe^{-kt}Ae^{ct}
$$

Now using the product rule backwards we get: 
$$
\frac{dAe^{ct}y}{dt} = kxe^{-kt}Ae^{ct}
$$

Then I integrated to get:
$$
Ae^{ct}y = \int({kxe^{-kt}Ae^{ct}})dt
$$
$$
Ae^{ct}y = \frac{kxe^{-kt}Ae^{ct}}{c-k}
$$

Thus,
$$
y=\frac{kxe^{-kt}Ae^{ct}}{(c-k)(Ae^{ct})}
$$

however, it seems that I have done something wrong since the answer is:

$$
y = Ae^{ct}+\frac{kxe^{-kt}}{k-c}
$$

Could you tell me where I may have gone wrong?

Comment: [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) might be a better site for this question.

Comment: I don't think your third equation is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decay rate of the mother isotope $x$ depends only on the amount of $x$, so that:

$$\frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t}=-kx(t)$$
This solves easily:
$$\ln x=-kt +C$$
Initial condition: $t=0, x=x_0$
$$\ln x_0=C$$
$$\ln\Big(\frac{x}{x_0}\Big)=-kt$$
$$\boxed{x(t)=x_0e^{-kt}}$$
The rate of formation of the daughter isotope $y$ equals the decay rate of $x$ to $y$, minus the decay of $y$:
$$\Big(\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}\Big)_{\text{Total}} = \Big(\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}\Big)_{\text{x decay}} - \Big(\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}\Big)_{\text{y decay}}$$
Or:
$$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}=-\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}-cy$$
$$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}=kx_0e^{-kt}-cy$$
$$y'+cy=kx_0e^{-kt}$$
This is a linear, 1st order, inhomogeneous DE, which can be integrated with an integrating factor:

$$I=\int e^{ct}\text{d}t$$

I'll leave that to you.

---

Your third equation:
$$\frac{dy}{dt} + cx = kxe^{-kt}$$
makes little sense. It's a differential equation in **three variables**: $x$, $y$ and $t$.

Answer (score 0):

You have used $Ae^{ct}$ as full solution to the inhomogeneous differential equation. It is not. I can't put the whole calculations as this is HW exercise, but I can say that $Ae^{ct}$ is the homogeneous solution to inhomogeneous differential equation. To your homogeneous solution, you have to add inhomogeneous part to get full solution. Notice the correct answer is of the form $$y(t)=y_{homogeneous}(t)+y_{inhomogeneous}(t)$$.